# Different output delays for internal to output and input to output path

Tags: fpga, clock, timing, timing-analysis, sdc

I am trying to get correct timing constraints for a ULPI interface, where the PHY is an external chip and the link is an FPGA. The clock is generated by the PHY.

[image: IO configuration diagram]

The timing constraints from internal FFs to the output pins of the FPGA are straightforward:

```
# There is an external 2.4ns delay on the clock between the PHY and the link. 
# Model this as a virtual clock with negative 2.4ns latency...

create_clock -name {ulpi_clk} -period 16.600 [get_ports {ulpi_clk}]
create_clock -name {ulpi_clk_phy} -period 16.600 
set_clock_latency -source -2.4 [get_clocks {ulpi_clk_phy}]

# The ULPI specification has a 6ns input delay on signals from the link
# to the PHY. This becomes a 6ns output delay for the link.

set_output_delay -add_delay  -clock [get_clocks {ulpi_clk_phy}]  6 [get_ports {ulpi_data[*]}] -max
```

So far so good: when I run this through Quartus, everything works.

There is also a `ulpi_dir` signal that goes from the phy to the link. It goes to FFs inside the link but also to the output enable of the bidirectional
`ulpi_data` pins.

Every time there is a change in bus direction, there is a turn-around cycle during
which the PHY won't drive the bus to avoid bus contention.

The output delay of the PHY is 9ns, which translates into a 9ns input delay on the link:

```
set_input_delay -add_delay  -clock [get_clocks {ulpi_clk_phy}]  9.0 [get_ports {ulpi_dir}] -max
set_input_delay -add_delay  -clock [get_clocks {ulpi_clk_phy}]  0.0 [get_ports {ulpi_direction}] -min
```

There is a combinatorial path from the `ulpi_dir` input to the `ulpi_data` pins through the output enable. When I run timing analysis with this 9ns input delay constraint, the Timing Analyzer applies a 9ns input delay on `ulpi_dir`, and it applies the 6ns output delay of `ulpi_data` for a total of 15ns and a 16.6ns clock. This results in a 4ns timing violation on `ulpi_data`:

[image: Timing Violation Waveform]

In reality, the 6ns output delay should only be used for the internal FFs of the link to `ulpi_data`, not for `ulpi_dir` to `ulpi_data`: we want `ulpi_data` to stop driving the bus before the rising edge of the next clock, but since it's turn-around cycle, we don't care about the input delay during that cycle.

How do I do this?

Ideally, I want to `set_output_delay` only for paths from internal FFs to `ulpi_data`, but it only supports targets, not sources?

Comment: Are you familiar with `set_max_delay`. I think what you need is something like: `set_max_delay -from [get_registers *] -to [get_ports ulpi_data] 10.000`

Comment: Wasn't that a typo: "internal FFs to ulpi_dir", I think you meant "internal FFs to ulpi_data"

Comment: @MituRaj It's one option, but it has the problem that it removes all notion of the clock and the delays related to the clock input path and clock tree to these FFs. You'd have to use a delay of (16.6 - 6.0 - 2.4 (external clock delay) - ??? (internal clock delay). I was hoping that there's way to make the timing analyzer do all that work for me. Especially since some of the internal clock delay can be synthesis dependent, so it would change each run.

Comment: @MituRaj Yes, that was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: That's not right. That's right for `set_max_delay -datapath_only`. But `set_max_delay` takes into consideration clock skew, latency, uncertainty etc.

Comment: I think I understood your comment. Seems like you are talking about the skews. Yes the source latency is given by you, and the network latency to the flop is known to the tool. But external network latency at the destination is not known, so the difference in network latencies should be given as skew which may have to be embedded in the max_delay constraint as 16-6-∆. This is an information user has to give. But this has to be considered for set_output_delay and set_input_delay as well.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. But you're right: the internal skew is known by the tool, and it is indeed included. So your answer is correct. I also had to add this: `set_max_delay -from [get_ports {ulpi_direction}] -to [get_ports {ulpi_data[*]}] 14.2
`, to make it fully work. Can you add that to your answer? Note that it's 14.2 (16.6-2.4), not (16.6-2.4-9) because the 9 is already included with the earlier `set_input_delay`.

Comment: That's right. But since the clock definition point is within your FPGA part, the source latency 2.4 has to be substracted in set max delay for flop to output port path. It will be skew to the external destination flop.

Comment: Just a side question- how did you estimate the value 2.4 ns as source latency?

Comment: The board designer added a voltage level shifter on `ulpi_clk` only. This introduces a 2.4ns delay. ([Sigh](https://twitter.com/tom_verbeure/status/1398515158842966016?s=21))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ideally, I want to set_output_delay only for paths from internal FFs to ulpi_dir, but it only supports targets, not sources?

Yes, it's possible in SDC. You can use the `set_max_delay` and `set_min_delay` instead. For e.g, if I really understood your requirement on `ulpi_data`:

```
set_max_delay -from [get_registers *] -to [get_ports ulpi_data] 8.200
```

Where \$8.200\$ is obtained as the timing window available: clock period - input delay + skew at destination flop: \$16.600 - 6.00 + (-2.400) = 8.200 \text{ ns}\$

This constraint will be used for setup analysis of all timing paths from flops to the output port `ulpi_data`.

Similarly for input-to-output delay from `ulpi_dir` to `ulpi_data`:

```
set_max_delay -from [get_ports ulpi_dir] -to [get_ports ulpi_data] 14.200
```

Where \$14.200\$ is obtained as the timing window available: clock period + skew at destination flop: \$16.600 + (-2.400) = 14.200 \text { ns}\$